# Formatting the svn log output

Tags: svn, formatting, changelog

I have been generating change logs in subversion using the `svn log` command. To make it easier to read, I'd like to add a newline after each revision's comments. If the output initially appears like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like it to appear like this instead:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision 1


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision 2


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried using the following command in batch:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (starting_revision, 1, ending_revision) DO (

svn log branch_name -r %%i --incremental >> output.txt
echo. >> output.txt
echo. >> output.txt

)
```

This seemed to work initially, but since not every one of the revisions was made to the branch I am working on, it ended up printing extra newlines in some parts of the text file. Does anyone know how I might avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`--xml`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) option with the [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command-line. Parsing xml'ed output will allow you to format it in any way you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you want one line log then you can use

```
svn log | perl -l40pe 's/^-+/\n/'
```

I want one line log so I used above command.

Comment: This is such a great answer! Piping the output gives you so many options. Thanks